# Index syntax makeindex vs xindy (range formatting)

Tags: xindy, makeindex

In a normal index generated with `makeindex` we can format a range using

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
test\index{test|(textbf}
\newpage
test\index{test}
\newpage
test\index{test|)}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

aka, we only need to specify `textbf` at the start.

Xindy does not like this, it needs `textbf` at the end as well (`|)textbf`).

I did some tests, and `makeindex` does not seem to mind `|)textbf` as long as it is the same as the start.

Is this feature documented somewhere?

I was looking in `texmf-dist/doc/support/makeindex/ind.pdf` which did not mention much about what could be written after `range_open/close`

---

Note that this will not work with `xindy` vs `hyperref` as `xindy` does not understand `\hyperindexformat`, but for what I'm going to use this for, this does not seem to matter